# Where to create External Question on Mechanical Turk

Tags: amazon-web-services, iframe, mechanicalturk, crowdsourcing

I am trying to create an ExternalQuestion, but I always receive an error. There is also no template for creating ExternalQuestions, so I just use the "other" template and paste the code below. 
I used the example code from the "External Question"-doc and I was expecting it to show me my website in an iframe:

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="https://example.com">
  <ExternalURL>https://example.com/task01</ExternalURL>
  <FrameHeight>0</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>
```

I thought that this might show my website in an iframe and appends the parameters for worker-ID and so on. But when I'm trying to post this I get the error
`Layout does not contain any fields for Workers to provide responses. Please include at least one field (input, select, or textarea)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I already found it. You HAVE TO use the boto3-SDK to post an external question

Comment: responding to yourself ain't ideal but thank you for posting your answer.

Comment: @deps_stats Actually, given a person who wants to share information on SO, a self-answer [is an encouraged activity](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).